# NextUI issue with multiple dropdown/popovers

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

I have this basic example made with NextUI the issue is whenever a popover or dropdown is open, to open the next one I have to click to close the other and then open the new one (basically I need to double click ) is there a way to fix this?

code:

```
<Popover
className="bg-white p-0 w-[240px] h-[100px] rounded-sm"
placement="right"
>
  <PopoverTrigger
    className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center"
  >
    <div>{trigger here}</div>
  </PopoverTrigger>
  <PopoverContent>

    example content
  </PopoverContent>
</Popover>
```

issue example:
https://ibb.co/4fMfhn6

The desired result with one click:
[Desired result with one click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERqtV.gif)

Answer (score 0):

**Popover** & **Dropdown** components have a "***shouldCloseOnInteractOutside***" event to use when user interacts with argument elements outside of the ref.

```html
<Dropdown
  shouldCloseOnInteractOutside={(e) => false}
>
  {children}
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround but to expand on @Steve Martin's answer, you can return false on the `shouldCloseOnInteractOutside` event and close the open dropdown by manually triggering a click.

E.g.

```
const handleOutsideDropdownClick = e => {
    const expandedDropdown = document.querySelector('[aria-haspopup="true"][aria-expanded="true"]');
    if (expandedDropdown && expandedDropdown !== e) {
        expandedDropdown.click();
    }
    return false;
};

<Popover shouldCloseOnInteractOutside={handleOutsideDropdownClick}>
    ...
</Popover>
```